# i need to change the default page of codeigniter website

Tags: codeigniter

i have a codeigniter website

even the default controller is Welcome

http://www.immodernafrican.com/index.php/Welcome

but this website is not opening on http://www.immodernafrican.com can anyone help me regarding this issue

Thanks

Regards

Comment: codeigniter version 3 or 2?

Comment: @RazibAlMamun Version 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please insure your controller file name first character Uppercase `Welcome.php`

and can insure your `$route['default_controller'] = "Welcome";`

Class names must start with an uppercase letter.

This is valid:

```
<?php
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

}
```

This is not valid:

```
<?php
class welcome extends CI_Controller {

}
```

Also `.htaccess` copy and paste :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Also insure `$config['uri_protocol']    = 'AUTO';` in `application/config/config.php` file

Comment: both are using upercase

Comment: also Class names must start with an uppercase letter. i edited my asnwer

Comment: the Class name is also in uppercase but still the issue isn't resolved

Comment: "Hello World" content which controller?

Comment: this mean the site is not working .. its hosted on rdp

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]                              this is the .htaccess file code